# ruby search drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list of `Type` in my `Products` model.

I want to be able to search in the `Products` index.html.erb so a user selects a type from a drop down list, clicks search and all the products matching that type are returned.

I can get normal search methods working where the user enters in their search in a text box but I cannot get it working when they just select from a dropdown.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Would prefer to do this without having to add more plugins

Answer (score 1):

In your controller :

```
def index
  @products = Product.all :conditons => {:type => params[:type]}
end
```

In your view:

```
<% form_tag products_path, :method => :get do %>
  <%=select_tag :type, options_for_select(Product::TYPES.map{ |type| [type, type]}), :onchange => "this.form.submit();" %>
  <%=submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

NB: The options_for_select accepts an array of pairs as [label, value], so we use map to build it.

Comment: I store Type in Product as a String.
In the Product model I set the options for Type with  
TYPES = ["type1", "type2"]

Comment: And the code I posted doesn't work? Does it give you an error?

Comment: My issue is I can't get it to actually search as I don't know how to with a dropdown, this is what I have in the index.html.erb   

find type <%= select("product", "type", Product::TYPES)%>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => "submit_search", :class => "button" %>

Comment: Still having trouble on that, get an error undefined method `TYPES' for #<Class:0x72a1f50>. <%=select_tag :type, options_for_select(Product.TYPES.map{ |type| [type, type]})

Comment: Mayby then `Product::TYPES` would help? This really depends on your code - you need to get the values for the select from somewhere - the best place is your model where they are already defined.